# Apache2 log to know WHEN the service was stoped/started

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, logging

I want to check if the apache service was stoped/restarted yesterday, but I can't find a log to tell . Just access and error logs.

Can you tell me how can I determine if apache2 service was stopped? (Ubuntu server)

Regards

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Im using Ubuntu server

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS  and /var/log/daemon.log is missing ¿?